# Sequelize: Issue in bulkCreate while inserting an array

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, postman, bulkinsert

I am trying to bulk insert the data coming from request body and getting trouble in inserting it into the Database.

I've tried `bulkCreate(JSON.parse(req.body.myData.toString())` but it didn't work as expected.

I have tried other solutions related to my problem and getting different kind of errors.

This is **myData**:

```
myData:
{ id: 121, anotherId: 3},
{ id: 122, anotherId: 3},
{ id: 123, anotherId: 3}
```

This is my **bulkCreate method**:

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(req.body.myData.toString()));
    // Save to PostgreSQL database
    MyData.bulkCreate([req.body.myData])
        .then(myData=> {        
            // Send created MyData to client
            res.status(200).json(myData);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({msg: "error", details: err});
        });
};
```

I have tried adding the `req.body.myData` as an array like:  `bulkCreate([req.body.myData])`

Kindly let me know where am I doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the issue I was passing in Postman. I changed the Header to `Content-Type: application/json` and passed the data as Raw format as follows:

```
{ "myData": 
   [ { "id": "121", "anotherId": "3" }, 
     { "id": "122",  "anotherId": "3" }, 
     { "id": "123", "anotherId": "3"} ] 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you defined myData model correctly.

myData should be collection in request body.

```
myData: [
   { id: 121, anotherId: 3},
   { id: 122, anotherId: 3},
   { id: 123, anotherId: 3}
]
```

and then

```
MyData.bulkCreate(req.body.myData)
  .then(myData=> {
    .....
  }).catch(err => {
    .....
  });
```

Comment: It shows this error: `TypeError: records.map is not a function` @Lee

Comment: With `.bulkCreate` you need to pass an array of objects that will be turned into rows.

Comment: This is what I'm passing using postman:
`myData:[ { id: 121, anotherId: 3}, { id: 122, anotherId: 3}, { id: 123, anotherId: 3} ]`
@Lee